# Converting MySQL to SQL Server

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I'm trying to run the following query (against Foodmart 2000), which runs fine on MySQL. On SQL Server 2005, all I get is a "Syntax error near '" message.

```
SELECT * FROM ((SELECT COUNT(state_province) AS 'WA'
                FROM customer c1
                WHERE c1.state_province LIKE 'WA'
                GROUP BY c1.state_province) as t1,
               (SELECT COUNT(state_province) AS 'OR'
                FROM customer c1
                WHERE c1.state_province LIKE 'OR'
                GROUP BY c1.state_province) as t2,
               (SELECT COUNT(state_province) AS 'CA'
                FROM customer c1
                WHERE c1.state_province LIKE 'CA'
                GROUP BY c1.state_province) as t3);
```

What exactly causes this problem?

Comment: I think you should give an alias name for main table. `SELECT * FROM (.....) tbl`

Comment: What's the input and what's the expected output of that query ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this; single `SELECT` using `SUM` instead of `COUNT`

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN state_province LIKE 'WA' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'WA',
       SUM(CASE WHEN state_province LIKE 'OR' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'OR',
       SUM(CASE WHEN state_province LIKE 'CA' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'CA'
FROM customer --c1
--GROUP BY c1.state_province
```

**Edit:** Working demo, [SQL Fiddle here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/cc7b9/15)

Answer (score 2):

You are missing an alias:

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
(
  select *
  from 
  (SELECT COUNT(state_province) AS 'WA'
   FROM customer c1
   WHERE c1.state_province LIKE 'WA'
   GROUP BY c1.state_province) as t1,
  (SELECT COUNT(state_province) AS 'OR'
   FROM customer c1
   WHERE c1.state_province LIKE 'OR'
   GROUP BY c1.state_province) as t2,
   (SELECT COUNT(state_province) AS 'CA'
    FROM customer c1
    WHERE c1.state_province LIKE 'CA'
    GROUP BY c1.state_province) as t3
) src;  -- < add this alias
```

You **must** have an alias on all derived tables and subqueries.

You can also use a version of @Kaf's still with `count` by using the following:

```
SELECT count(CASE WHEN state_province LIKE 'WA' THEN 1 ELSE null END) AS 'WA',
       count(CASE WHEN state_province LIKE 'OR' THEN 1 ELSE null END) AS 'OR',
       count(CASE WHEN state_province LIKE 'CA' THEN 1 ELSE null END) AS 'CA'
FROM customer
```

see [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/cc7b9/30)

Comment: I just tried running exactly that, and I still get the same error.

Comment: Adding comments doesn't help, see [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/cc7b9/14/1).

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM (Select (SELECT COUNT(state_province) AS 'WA'
                FROM customer c1
                WHERE c1.state_province LIKE 'WA'
                GROUP BY c1.state_province) as t1,
               (SELECT COUNT(state_province) AS 'OR'
                FROM customer c1
                WHERE c1.state_province LIKE 'OR'
                GROUP BY c1.state_province) as t2,
               (SELECT COUNT(state_province) AS 'CA'
                FROM customer c1
                WHERE c1.state_province LIKE 'CA'
                GROUP BY c1.state_province) as t3) a ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just leave out the braces around your from subselects and remove the `group by`, they are unnecessary

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT COUNT(state_province) AS 'WA'
               FROM customer c1
               WHERE c1.state_province LIKE 'WA') as t1,
              (SELECT COUNT(state_province) AS 'OR'
               FROM customer c1
               WHERE c1.state_province LIKE 'OR') as t2,
              (SELECT COUNT(state_province) AS 'CA'
               FROM customer c1
               WHERE c1.state_province LIKE 'CA') as t3;
```

See [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/cc7b9/20/0) for testing.

Answer (score 0):

I'd rather `PIVOT` my data

```
SELECT [WA] AS [WA], [OR] AS [OR], [CA] AS [CA] FROM
(SELECT state_province FROM customer) C
PIVOT
(
  COUNT(C.state_province) FOR state_province IN ([WA],[OR],[CA])
) AS pivoted
```

[Fiddle here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/56079/3)

Answer (score 0):

Well, first of all, thanks for all the suggestions. All of you were right, I was missing an alias. Also, as it turns out, I had to add a "use foodmart2000" before the statement.
Stupid me :)

Answer (score 0):

@bluefeet and @bummi are extremely close.  The issue is that you can't use the `as` keyword with table aliases in SQL Server:

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
(
  (SELECT COUNT(state_province) AS 'WA'
   FROM customer c1
   WHERE c1.state_province LIKE 'WA'
   GROUP BY c1.state_province) t1,
  (SELECT COUNT(state_province) AS 'OR'
   FROM customer c1
   WHERE c1.state_province LIKE 'OR'
   GROUP BY c1.state_province) t2,
   (SELECT COUNT(state_province) AS 'CA'
    FROM customer c1
    WHERE c1.state_province LIKE 'CA'
    GROUP BY c1.state_province) t3
) src;
```

You will probably get better performance from @kaf's example, however.